# Table cell height bug in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-tables

I made a CSS table with a CSS table inside it. When I use vertical-align at the inner one it doesn't rendering it correctly when I resize it (make it smaller, then bigger). It still as height as the highest point

Look at this codepen and resize the window. Make it really small. Wait for 1-2 seconds. Then Make the window larger. Notice that the height of the table-cell doesnt goes back.

Annoying! Anyone knows a fix?

http://codepen.io/iamrane/pen/hklxj

Here it is in fullscreen: http://cdpn.io/hklxj

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug in chromes bug list:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=241331&q=vertical-align&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 0):

Very annoying!

If you are desperate to get this working you could force Chrome to redraw the element (on window resize, maybe?):

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("table-list")[0];

elem.style.display = "none";

elem.style.display = "table";
```

Comment: yeah but its nothing i want do to. But I manage to fix it. But strangly when i added verticle align to my code it worked now. But not when i didnt specifiy it. Strange